# Can I find out the angles of a rectangle given the sidelengths and that 2 of the sides are parallel?

Tags: rectangles

Not really a big brain when it comes to math.

First question here... hope it meets the standards.

Let's say I've got a quadrilateral, I know the side lengths, and I know two of the sides are parallel. Can I figure out the angles?

Comment: Which angles do you mean? By definition, the internal angles of a rectangle are 90°, for instance?

Comment: "Rectangle" is the wrong word. It means a quadrilateral with all angles $90^o$. Presumably you must mean a quadrilateral (ie a figure with 4 sides).

Comment: In case you mean a trapezoid, the question is not trivial.  Can you construct the  trapezoid from the given sides?  Hint If $AB$ and $CD$ are parallel, draw a parallel of $AD$ trough $C$.

Comment: @almagest Sorry for that. Mixed up my English. Quadrilateral it is.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe AB are parallel, but CD are not. I just know the sidelengths of all of them.

Comment: @m.a.a. I refer $A$ to $D$ to be the edges of the trapezoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quadrilateral with 2 parallel sides is a [trapezoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trapezoid.html). Since you know all 4 side lengths you can calculate the length of the diagonals. Select one diagonal and find its length (e.g. use equation 10 in the above link). You now have 2 triangles where all side lengths are known. Finding angles in such triangles is [easy](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sss-triangles.html).